# Why are the unit numbers changed when PCI cards are added or changed (Linux Zorin...)?

Tags: linux, devices

PCI card removal with nvidia processor Installation of a graphics card (AMD) in another PCI express slot. Moving another PCI card Reboot

NO wifi...

After some research, I discovered that the NetworkManager wifi unit configuration did not correspond to that calculated by udev (I presume).

/etc/NetworkManager/system-connection/

One entry by network...

Before changing PCI card, wifi unit name is wlp6s0

[connection]
id=dlink6422
uuid=460c5501-b4e0-40c4-a726-5a03cc2ab51a
type=wifi
interface-name=wlp6s0
permissions=
timestamp=1679436128``
and so on

After the changes, the unit name is wlp8s0 and this change is not present in the configuration file.

Proceed with the change to restart wifi.

[connection]
id=dlink6422
uuid=460c5501-b4e0-40c4-a726-5a03cc2ab51a
type=wifi
interface-name=wlp8s0
permissions=
timestamp=1679436128